# Change of variable multiple integrals: Polar did not work

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

How could I solve the following problem to compute:
$$\int_{R}x^2+y^2\,dx\,dy$$ over region R bounded by the polar curve $r=1+\cos{\theta}$ from $\theta \in [0,pi]$ and the x-axis?

I have attempted to apply a polar change of variable, but have only managed to reduce it to:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}4\cos^{8}{\frac{\theta}{2}}\, d\theta$$ 
which is clearly not simple enough.

Comment: So, the question boils down to evaluating a trigonometric integral.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\iint_R (x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^\pi \int_{0}^{1+\cos(\theta)}r^3 \,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac14\int_0^\pi (1+\cos(\theta))^4\,d\theta\\\\
&=4\int_0^\pi \cos^8(\theta/2)\,d\theta\\\\
&=8\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^8(\theta)\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

Using the reduction formula for the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n(\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{n-1}{n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{n-2}(\theta)\,d\theta$, we find that

$$8\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^8(\theta)\,d\theta\right)=8\left(\frac78 \cdot \frac56\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac12\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{35\pi}{32}$$